# Different solution on trigonometric function in mathematica and wolframalpha using Simplify and FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have this expresion:

```
-cos(a3) (cos(a2) sin(a1) + cos(a1) sin(a2))
```

And when I simplify with wolframalpha online, it give me this:

```
-cos(a3) sin(a1 + a2)
```

that is the correct simplification but when I do the same operation with mathematica using simplify, fullsimplify and trigreduce it give the same first expresion. 
I know that wolframalpha is using the next trigonometric identities:

```
sin(a+b) = sin(a)*cos(b)+sin(b)*cos(a)
```

but my question is if mathematica don't have this identities include and how I can include

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mathematica, the way you indicate function arguments is with square brackets `[]`.  As well, built-in functions like sine and cosine are written with capitals, i.e. `Sin` and `Cos`.  So the way you'd write your expression for mathematica would be like this:

```
(-Cos[a3] (Cos[a2] Sin[a1] + Cos[a1] Sin[a2]))
```

And if you apply `Simplify` to this, you get

```
In[1]:= Simplify[(-Cos[a3] (Cos[a2] Sin[a1] + Cos[a1] Sin[a2]))]

Out[1]= -(Cos[a3] Sin[a1 + a2])
```